# Validate date with jquery and help user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make a jQuery function which should check user value. The date format what I need is "YYYY-MM-DD". I want to insert "-" in the users text when the length is 5 and 8. What I make:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=date]').keydown(function(){
         var leng = $(this).val().length;
         var content = $(this).val();
         if(leng == 5){
            $(this).text(content+"-");
         }else if(leng == 8){
            $(this).text(content+"-");        
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="date" name="openDatePerm1" class="form-control"
       id="openDatePerm1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="10">
```

It isn't insert "-" when it should (it do it never). What I do wrong?

Comment: Your mistake:   $(this).val(content+"-"); Not $(this).text();

Comment: Any chance that you would take a look at the provided answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this).val(content+"-");`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign by using `$(this).val(..)`, and not `$(this).text(..)`, then just shift your variables by one, so `(leng == 4)` rather than `(leng == 5)` and `(leng == 7)` rather than `(leng == 8)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=date]').keydown(function(){
         var leng = $(this).val().length;
         console.log(leng)      
         var content = $(this).val();
         if(leng == 4){
            $(this).val(content+"-");
         }else if(leng == 7){
            $(this).val(content+"-");        
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="openDatePerm1" class="form-control" id="openDatePerm1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 What the OP describes is where there browser doesn't support for `date` (*in fact I answered this on FF where it's not supported*). When typing into the input the numbers 1 to 8 for the user you get `12345678`, but the user wants it to be in the format: `1234-56-78` and add the dashes while the user types.

Answer (score 0):

> make a jQuery function which should check user value. The date format
>   what I need is "YYYY-MM-DD"

It is not necessary to insert `"-"` at `input type="date"` value . If `this.checkValidity()` returns `true` , input `value` should be valid , including `"-"` between each `YYYY` , `MM` , `DD` . To view resulting string use `this.value` , to view value as `Date` string use `this.valueAsDate` . To make certain that each `YYYY` , `MM` , `DD` are set , try also setting `minlength` attribute to `10`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=date]").change(function() {
         console.log(this.checkValidity(), this.value, this.valueAsDate)
    });
});
```

```css
input[type="date"]:invalid ~ label[for="input"]:after {
  color:red;
  content:"Invalid date ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="openDatePerm1" class="form-control" id="openDatePerm1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="10" minlength="10"><br>
<label for="input"></label>
```

Alternatively, using `pattern` attribute with `RegExp`

```
(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))
```

See [HTML5 Pattern - Dates](http://html5pattern.com/Dates)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=text]").change(function() {
    console.log(this.checkValidity(), this.value, this.valueAsDate)
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]:invalid ~ label[for="input"]:after {
  color: red;
  content: "Invalid date. Required date format: YYYY-MM-DD ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="openDatePerm1" class="form-control" id="openDatePerm1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="10" minlength="10" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))">
<br>
<label for="input"></label>
```

Comment: How is it not possible?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Adjusted text at post to "not necessary"

Comment: Yes but the OP is asking specifically on how to add dashes, rather then the validation part.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Not certain interpret Question correctly ?  Where would `"-"` be added ? The dashes / hyphens are automatically added to `input type="date"` value . Why would additional `"-"` be added to value ?

Comment: Looks like it's because the users browser doesn't support `type="date"` because they are describing it being typed in as a normal textbox. That or the are adding that for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Perhaps OP will chime in , describe why this process is needed ; what expected result is ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution almost got it right, here a small tweak to yours.

1- the correct function to use is `$(this).val(content+"-");` using the function `val()` not `text()` as in your example:  `$(this).text(content+"-");`

2- users might need to delete/erase using backspace, then there should be an exception for it. Otherwise the function will keep re-adding the previous content and the user won't be able to delete his input.

3- the number of chars are: 4 and 7 not 5 and 8. Because the first **'-'** should be inserted after exactly 4 digits e.g. 1999 then **'-'**. After that the month which is two digits added to the year plus one hyphen 4+1+2 is 7 digits in total.

Here is a working solution:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wdugau7u/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('input[type=date]').keydown(function() {
        //Capture the field object
        $field = $(this);
        //Verify if the user is trying to delete or add new chars
        $('html').keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 8) {} else {
            //alert("here");
            //Call the function that will count the chars and add '-'
            addDash($field);
          }
        });
      });

      function addDash($field) {
        var leng = $field.val().length;
        var content = $field.val();
        if (leng == 4) {
          $field.val(content + "-");
        } else if (leng == 7) {

          $field.val(content + "-");
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="openDatePerm1" class="form-control" id="openDatePerm1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="10">
```